# Export orders from Wordpress Woocommerce as XML automatically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to export an XML (and upload to FTP) with order information as well as delivery and invoice address from Wordpress Woocommerce automatically when someone places an order in the shop. How can I do that as easy as possible?

Comment: You definitely don't need FTP for this - as WP runs on the server, you can save it to the server. More details are needed as to how you want the XML to be formed.

Comment: I need to upload on ftp to another server. If I get a easy tip how to auto xml I can figure out the formatting. Tags with product name and shipping address is a good start.